# BeanUtils: populate String Date formatted map field to Date property

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

I've this `Map<String, Object>`:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("date", "02/11/2018@11:29:03.463+0000");
```

My bean is:

```
public class MyBean {
  private Date date;
  // setters & getters
}
```

I'm trying to populate my map to bean:

```
MyBean bean = new MyBean();
BeanUtilsBean.getInstance().populate(bean, map);
```

I'm getting this error message:

> ConversionException: DateConverter does not support default String to 'Date' conversion.

**IMPORTANT**: I can't change string format.

How could I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an instance of `DateTimeConverter` and pass in your custom patterns. Here is an example:

```
DateTimeConverter dateConverter = new DateConverter(null);
dateConverter.setPatterns(new String[] {"dd/MM/yyyy@HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"});
ConvertUtils.register(dateConverter, Date.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to register converter:

```
class MyDateConverter implements Converter {
   private final DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy@HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
   public Object convert(Class type, Object value) {
       if(value == null) {
           return null;
       } else { // parse your date format with date formatter
           try {
               return format.parse((String) value);
           } catch (ParseException e) {
               throw new RuntimeException(e);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
ConvertUtilsBean convertUtilsBean = new ConvertUtilsBean();
convertUtilsBean.register(new MyDateConverter(), Date.class);

BeanUtilsBean beanUtilsBean =
          new BeanUtilsBean(convertUtilsBean, new PropertyUtilsBean());

MyBean bean = new MyBean();
beanUtilsBean.populate(bean, map);
```